# Erroneous Results with random two state benchmark

Tags: c++, random

I ran this code for a preliminary benchmark, which compares the time taken to generate a certain number of random states using the **scale a double random value** and using a **Bernoulli distribution**. The code is below:

> ```
> int main()
> {
>
>   std::random_device s;
>   std::mt19937 engine(s());
>   std::bernoulli_distribution bernp50(0.5000000000000000);
>   std::uniform_real_distribution<double> d;
>   
>   long int limit = 10000000000; //10^10
>   int counter[2] = {0};
>
>
>   {
>       Timer bernstate("Bern Two States");
>       for(int i = limit; i>0; i--)
>       {
>               int tmp = bernp50(engine); 
>               //Implicit bool to int conversion
>               counter[tmp]++;
>       }
>   }
>   cout << " Bern Two States - 0,1 \n\nCounter:\n" << "0: " << 
>   counter[0] <<"\n1: " << counter[1]<<"\n"
>   << "Counter additions:  " << counter[0] + counter[1] << "\n\n"
>   << "\n0:  " << (double)((double)counter[0]*100/(double)limit) << "%" 
>   << "\n1:  " << (double)((double)counter[1]*100/(double)limit) << "%"
>   << "\n\n" << endl;
>   
>   counter[0]=0;
>   counter[1]=0;
>
>   {
>       Timer double_comp("Two State - Double");
>       for(int i = limit; i>0; i--)
>       {
>               double temp = d(engine)*2;
>               if(temp < 1)
>               {
>                   counter[0]++;
>               }
>               else
>               {
>                   counter[1]++;
>               }
>       }
>   }
>
>   cout << " Double Two States - 0,1 \n\nCounter:\n" << "0: " << 
>   counter[0] <<"\n1: " << counter[1]<<"\n"
>   << "Counter additions:  " << counter[0] + counter[1] << "\n\n"
>   << "\n0:  " << (double)((double)counter[0]*100/(double)limit) << "%" 
>   << "\n1:  " << (double)((double)counter[1]*100/(double)limit) << "%"
>   << "\n\n" << endl;
>
> } //End of Main()
> ```

For `limit = 10^10` I get the result, where the counter additions is greater than the limit variable. Same for `10^11`:

> ```
> Timer Object: Bern Two States Timer Object Destroyed: Bern Two States Duration Elapsed:  85.9409 s
>
>  Bern Two States - 0,1
>
> Counter: 0: 705044031 1: 705021377 Counter additions:  1410065408
>
>
> 0:  7.05044% 1:  7.05021%
>
>
> Timer Object: Two State - Double Timer Object Destroyed: Two State - Double Duration Elapsed:  87.6082 s
>
>  Double Two States - 0,1
>
> Counter: 0: 705029886 1: 705035522 Counter additions:  1410065408
>
>
> 0:  7.0503% 1:  7.05036%
> ```

However, for `limit = 10^9`, the results are fine:

> ```
> Timer Object: Bern Two States
> Timer Object Destroyed: Bern Two States
> Duration Elapsed:  62.5088 s
>
>  Bern Two States - 0,1
>
> Counter:
> 0: 500005067
> 1: 499994933
> Counter additions: 1000000000
>
>
> 0:  50.0005%
> 1:  49.9995%
>
>
> Timer Object: Two State - Double
> Timer Object Destroyed: Two State - Double
> Duration Elapsed:  62.6709 s
>
>  Double Two States - 0,1
>
> Counter:
> 0: 500015398
> 1: 499984602
> Counter additions: 1000000000
>
>
> 0:  50.0015%
> 1:  49.9985%
> ```

Comment: At first sight, it looks like your integer is overflowing.

Comment: It is overflow thanks. I made an error.

Comment: I actually used long int for the counters as well, but the problem was with the loop range iterator which was a 4-byte integer. The loop was actually messing up.

Comment: `long int` can in some configuration/systems still be only 4 bytes long. This leads me to a suggestion: If you for example expect to work with huge numbers, use the `<cstdint>` header. There you have for example `int64_t` which forces a 64-bit integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: I actually used long int for the counters as well, but the problem was with the loop range iterator which was a 4-byte integer. The loop was actually messing up.